# Stop Automated chat invitation when a customer initiated a chat from standard chat button

Tags: liveagent

How to stop invitation to pop up when customer is already chatting with Agent? Tried in below way but no luck

```
<div id="liveagent_button_online" style="display: none; border: 0px none; " >

        <img id="liveagent_enabled_button" 
            style="width:200px; cursor: pointer"
             onclick="startChatting()" 

    </div>
    <script>
        function startChatting(){
           var divdiv = document.getElementById('liveagent_invite_button_ID');
           divdiv.style.display = "none"; 
           liveagent.startChat('ButtonID')

        }
    </script>
 <div id="liveagent_invite_button_ID" style="display:none;"> 
     ---Invitation Code----
 </div>
```

Comment: No luck with this problem?